# How to remove bullets from numbered toctree in restructured text?

Tags: css, python-sphinx, toctree

I am using a `toctree` in [Sphinx](https://sphinx-doc.org) to automatically generate a table of contents for a webpage.

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :numbered:

   First
   Second
   Third
```

which creates (roughly):

- 1. First
- 2. Second
- 3. Third

I want the numbers, but I don't want the bullets. Is there some magic I'm missing that gives me the enumerated list without the bullets?

Answer (score 3):

That's a minor annoyance which can be corrected with a custom style.

```css
.toctree-wrapper ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

To override the default style sheet, you can add a custom style sheet to your static directory with the above style, then include it by [specifying it in the `conf.py`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_css_files):

```python
html_css_files = [
    'css/custom.css',
]
```