# Sphinx RTD theme: Change color of inline code

Tags: html, documentation, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I use [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/) with the [Read the Docs theme](https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/). For small inline code snippets, such as the mention of a single variable among a piece of text, I use double backticks to format the code as what's called "inline literals" in the [documentation](https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/demo/demo.html#inline-markup).

1. Is this the proper way to format inline code snippets?

Unlike proper code blocks, no language specific syntax highlighting is performed on the inline code snippets (that's fine). As seen in the linked documentation above (see the below screen shot), all such "inline literals" are colored red.

[image]

2. How can I change this color to something else?

I'm only concerned with the HTML output of Sphinx.

Comment: See how to override CSS with custom styles, such as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63820734/2214933).

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution, though it involves changing the Sphinx RTD theme source code.

The HTML coloring used by the RTD theme is specified in `sphinx_rtd_theme/static/css/theme.css`, with the `sphinx_rtd_theme` directory located in the `site-packages` directory of the Python installation. The red color used is `#e74c3c` and the specific place which sets this color for inline literals is

```
literal{color:#e74c3c}
```

Changing this color does exactly what I want. Making changes directly to `theme_css` feels wrong though. The specific change takes place on line 4, which is over 100000 characters wide! Clearly this file is generated from other files. I guess the proper solution involves performing the change do one of these (to me unknown) files.

### Edit: Proper solution

With a custom `.css` file, the colors of the inline literals can be set using

```css
code.literal {
    color: #404040 !important;
    background-color: #fbfbfb !important;
}
```

The name of a `.css` file containing the above should be added to `html_css_files` in the Sphinx `conf.py`, i.e.

```py
# conf.py
html_css_files = ['custom.css']
```

Comment: What version of sphinx were you using? I'm currently using v5 and this has no effect (literals are still red). Using firefox inspector I can see that the color is inherited from `tt.literal` so I added a `tt.literal` entry in `custom.css` similar to your original instructions—to no avail.

Comment: @drootang This works with Sphinx version 4.5.0.

Comment: I was struggling with this but eventually found that the CSS filename must be relative to the value set by `html_static_path`, which in my case was `_static`. See [sphinx docs](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_css_files)

Comment: @drootang Ah yes, that's right. Also, I can confirm that the above indeed works for Sphinx 5.3.0 as well.